# Image not being displayed [Xamarin.Forms][Syncfusion]

Tags: android, image, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am using Prism with Xamarin Forms with all the packages up to date. I am using SfRotator, SfNavigationDrawer etc. in my project but my issue is with the SfRotator. The images in the rotator are not being displayed. I have tried using the control which was not displaying any images. I moved to FFImageLoading which works outside the SfRotator but not inside. Also, if i put a inside the , or if i use a CachedImageFastRenderer, it throws a NullReferenceException

Following are the code snippets:

MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="xxxxxx.Views.MainPage"
xmlns:navDrawer="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfNavigationDrawer.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfNavigationDrawer.XForms"
xmlns:tabView="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.TabView;assembly=Syncfusion.SfTabView.XForms"
xmlns:rotator="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfRotator.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfRotator.XForms"
xmlns:listView="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.ListView.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms"
xmlns:ffimage="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
Title="{Binding Title}">
<tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
                                    <ScrollView>
                                        <StackLayout>                                        
                                            <rotator:SfRotator ItemsSource="{Binding ImageCollection}"  BackgroundColor="Blue" x:Name="rotator" NavigationStripMode="Dots" NavigationStripPosition="Bottom" NavigationDelay="100" NavigationDirection="Horizontal">                                               
<rotator:SfRotator.ItemTemplate>                                                   
<DataTemplate>                                                       
<ffimage:CachedImage ErrorPlaceholder="Error" Source="{Binding Image}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" LoadingPlaceholder="Loading..." />
                                                        <!--<Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource EmptyConverter}}" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="200" />-->
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                    <!--<DataTemplate>
                                                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>-->
                                                    <!--
                                                </rotator:SfRotator.ItemTemplate>-->
                                                </rotator:SfRotator.ItemTemplate>
                                            </rotator:SfRotator>
</StackLayout>                                  
</ScrollView>   
                            </tabView:SfTabItem.Content>                              
                        </tabView:SfTabItem>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
 public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

    private List imageCollection;
    public List ImageCollection
    {
    get { return imageCollection; }
    set { SetProperty(ref imageCollection, value); }
    }
    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    : base(navigationService)
    {
    Title = "Main Page";

    ImageCollection = new List();
    ImageCollection.Add(new OfferSection ("offer1.jpg", "1" ));
    ImageCollection.Add(new OfferSection ("offer2.jpg", "2" ));
    ImageCollection.Add(new OfferSection ("offer3.png", "3" ));
    }
```

OfferSection.cs

```
public class OfferSection
{

public string Image { get; set; }

public string OfferId { get; set; }

public OfferSection(string image, string id )
{
Image = image;
OfferId = id;
}
```

Thanks in advance. Waiting for a prompt response

Answer (score 0):

We confirm that we are able to reproduce the issue "**Image is not being displayed in rotator in android**". We have logged a bug report for this issue and the fix will be available 2018 Volume 4 SP1 which is expected to be rolled out by **first week of Feb 2019**.

**Note**: I work for Syncfusion.